# Is there a way to set the user in org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to migrate a curl command with a `username` and `password` to a rest API consumer code of `org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate`

```
curl -i -k --location -u username:userpass \
--request GET http://myserver:80/rest/api/2/project --header 'Accept: application/json' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-raw ''
```

But such parameter username:password is not supported in RestTemplate (correct me if I'm wrong)
What other options can do this?
I'm using spring boot 2.4.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `-u` or `--user`, Curl will Encode the credentials into Base64 and produce a header like this: `-H Authorization: Basic <Base64EncodedCredentials>`

There is a way to build a RestTemplate with what you want to achieve. To do that just configure a singleton restTemplate bean in your configuration class.

Until version 2.1.0 it was available the `basicAuthorization()`

[previous spring boot versions used basicAuthorization()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.6.RELEASE/api/index.html?org/springframework/boot/web/client/RestTemplateBuilder.html)

```
@Bean
RestTemplate rest(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
    restTemplateBuilder.basicAuthorization("username", "userpass").build();
}
```

From 2.1.0 and forward the `basicAuthorization()` has been deprecated and in later versions removed. You can use `basicAuthentication()` instead

[newer versions have only basicAuthentication()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/web/client/RestTemplateBuilder.html)

```
  @Bean
    RestTemplate rest(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
        restTemplateBuilder.basicAuthentication("username", "userpass").build();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @boug if you can change to `.basicAuthentication`. that would be perfect!

Comment: thnks have updated answer with relative info